# Should the spacebar activate tabs?

Tags: website-design, accessibility, tabs, space-bar

After you have navigated to an un-opened tab, via the use of the tab key, and it has the focus on the webpage:

Should the 'spacebar' keyboard key activate that tab and open it (as well as the default 'enter' key)? What are the guidelines for this behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Marco Zehe, Mozilla accessibility
QA engineer and evangelist, provided some advice in [an article about implementing tabs in web apps with WAI-ARIA](http://www.marcozehe.de/2013/02/02/advanced-aria-tip-1-tabs-in-web-apps/). He advocates cursor keys for moving focus between tabs in a set and then spacebar to activate the focused tab, which is consistent with the native desktop experience.

> Left and Right arrow keys should move focus to the new tab, but not
>   yet select it. **Space should actually perform the hiding and un-hiding
>   of the tab panels** and adjust the aria-selected attributes. This is how
>   Mac OS X applications with multiple tabs usually do it, for example
>   many multi-tab panels in the System Preferences. This makes sure the
>   user can change focus multiple times without each focus change
>   triggering a dynamic update and possibly network traffic. Only an
>   explicit step to select a tab should then actually trigger the change,
>   and traffic. Mouse or touch can trigger both at the same time. Tab
>   should immediately move to the first control within the tab panel. It
>   should skip over the remaining tabs.

I would normally implement tabs so that either spacebar or enter can be used.